# How to connect to the internal maven repository?

Tags: eclipse, maven

In our company we have an internal maven repository. The IDE used is eclipse.

The link to the internal maven repository is http://machinename:8080/artifactory

Can someone please help me how to connect to this internal maven repository and also what all changes are to be made on the eclipse to use this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your Maven settings.xml file to use the internal Artifactory repo, instead of the global maven repository.

In Eclipse go to Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings and edit the settings.xml file to contain your repository. e.g.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>profile_name_here</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>profile_id_here</id>
            <name>artifactory</name>
            <url>http://machinename:8080/artifactory</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</profile>
```

Comment: I am getting the below error message in Eclipse 

14/03/11 13:22:40 GMT: Unable to update index for id|http://machinename:8080/artifactory

Comment: Have you checked artifactory is actually running from that URL? What happens when you request it from your browser?